# Sending data to a generator in Python

Tags: python, generator

My objective is to get my head around the concept of sending data to a Python generator. Below is my code snippet and the unexpected output:

```
def spam():
    while True:
        received = yield
        print("Message received from generator function:", received)
        yield received


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = spam()
    print(s)
    next(s)
    names = ["Bob", "Nancy", "Daniela", "Martin"]
    for name in names:
        print(s.send(name))
```

Output :

```
7tvmb228:Own subhayan.bhattachary$ python test_generators.py 
<generator object spam at 0x10873aa20>
Message received from generator function: Bob
Bob
None
Message received from generator function: Daniela
Daniela
None
```

Can someone please point me out where is the None values coming from and how to solve that . My assumption is somehow that values do not get passed to the function. But why is that the case. Where am i going wrong .

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#passing-values-into-a-generator) states:

> Values are sent into a generator by calling its `send(value)` method. This method resumes the generator’s code and the `yield` expression returns the specified value. **If the regular `__next__()` method is called, the `yield` returns `None`.**

**Solution**

Put an additional `next(s)` after each send to 'flush' the `None` results.

```
def spam():
    while True:
        received = yield
        print("Message received from generator function:", received)
        yield received


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = spam()
    print(s)
    next(s)
    names = ["Bob", "Nancy", "Daniela", "Martin"]
    for name in names:
        print(s.send(name))
        next(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `None` values are coming from `received = yield`, which essentially means you are yielding `None` value. You need to have only one `yield` in your `spam()` function:

```
def spam():
    received = None
    while True:
        received = yield received
        print("Message received from generator function:", received)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = spam()
    print(s)
    next(s)
    names = ["Bob", "Nancy", "Daniela", "Martin"]
    for name in names:
        print(s.send(name))
```

Prints:

```
<generator object spam at 0x7f1518c8f9e8>
Message received from generator function: Bob
Bob
Message received from generator function: Nancy
Nancy
Message received from generator function: Daniela
Daniela
Message received from generator function: Martin
Martin
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:

> Because generator-iterators begin execution at the top of the generator's function body, there is no yield expression to receive a value when the generator has just been created.  Therefore, calling send() with a non-None argument is prohibited when the generator iterator has just started, and a TypeError is raised if this occurs (presumably due to a logic error of some kind).  Thus, before you can communicate with a coroutine you must first call next() or send(None) to advance its execution to the first yield expression.

So you may change your code like this:

```
def spam():
    while True:
        received = yield
        print("Message received from generator function:", received)
        yield received


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = spam()
    print(s)
    names = ["Bob", "Nancy", "Daniela", "Martin"]
    for name in names:
        next(s)
        print(s.send(name))
```